# study phd and second master at the same time at same program

Tags: phd, masters, canada

I am a phd student at Civil/Structural engineering program outside of Canada but now I want to study second master of Structural engineering (my research area will be difference from my first master) in Canada. I want to know if I can study both phd and master at the same time? my phd courses are finished and I am in phd research duration.

Comment: This sounds like a terrible idea. A PhD is a full time job. And a second MSc won't do much once you've completed your PhD.